# How to turn off the automatical popup?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I dont know if i can ask about this in this site, but there is nothing to get help.
sometimes, in using vscode, this popped up, it is very disturbing me.
how to remove this thing?
[image]

Comment: You do not like the info that tells you how to use it when you hover over methods?

Comment: yes, excatly I am.

Comment: One day when you work on huge code bases you will like it. lol  I think the setting is "peek definition"

Comment: I think it helps, thank you

Comment: I think its not 'peek definition', because its popping up when i am typing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable them completely by adding

```
{
  "editor.hover.enabled": false
}
```

to your settings.json.

However, a possible compromise to keep them while not allowing them to be so intrusive may be adding this instead:

```
{
  "editor.hover.sticky": false
}
```

Or maybe you need to disable the parameters hints? Then you could try this:

```
{
  // This below disables parameters hints
  "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
  // Or is this what you're looking for? 
  "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false
}
```

Comment: I think it is not about my problem. it keeps popping up, whenever i am typing.

Comment: Just edited my answer. See if this addresses your question (the last option).

Comment: "editor.parameterHints.enalbed" is what i want to. thx